# 'It ~ that' for emphasis

Tags: grammar

In It-cleft sentences, can ***which***  replace that?
For example,

> It was ancient history ***which*** attracted me.

[image: It-cleft]

Answer (score 1):

## Yes

The text that you copy specifically says that the relative clause may start with who, whom,. which, that, or have no introductory word at all. Not all oif these will be appropriate in every example. However both of:

- > It was ancient history which attracted me.
- > It was ancient history that attracted me.

are correct and idiomatic.  (A use of "who" would not be in this case.)